# How to extract strings out of tuples in python

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

This my list of tuples and each Tuple has one string and two boolean values:

```
[('r', True, True), (True, 'g', True), (True, True, 'b')]
```

I want to turn the above into this:

```
['r', 'g', 'b']
```

i.e replace every tuple in the list with the string inside of it.

notes:

1-assume that I don't know the position of each string in each tuple so I can't get it by indexing

2-assume that I have too many tuples.

I need a function that can be applied at any number of tuples inside a list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested list comprehension should be fine for what you need.

```
>>> tups = [('r', True, True), (True, 'g', True), (True, True, 'b')]
>>> [x for t in tups for x in t if isinstance(x, str)]
['r', 'g', 'b']
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also do it this way, getting the first `str` of each tuple, and stopping to test the rest once it's been found:

```
data = [('r', True, True), (True, 'g', True), (True, True, 'b')]

out = [ next(value for value in tup if isinstance(value, str)) for tup in data]

print(out)
#['r', 'g', 'b']
```

Comment: @RiccardoBucco according to my timings this solution is about two times slower than mine. Building a generator for a tuple of length three takes longer than just iterating over it. This answer is still fine for longer tuples, of course.

Comment: @timgeb That's right. I didn't expect it to be faster in this case either, for the reason you mention, and I would only have thought of using this solution for longer data. I just did some quick timing, though, because I was surprised by the first comment. I also found it to be twice as slow, but was surprised that it already gets faster when doubling the size of the tuples. I woudl have thought that building the generator was much more expensive...

Answer (score 0):

You could also flatten the list with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), then use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to filter only `str` types:

```py
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [('r', True, True), (True, 'g', True), (True, True, 'b')]
>>> [x for x in chain.from_iterable(l) if isinstance(x, str)]
['r', 'g', 'b']
```